# Don’t receive rewards even I have rebaged and movedup my account

Tags: polkadot, staking, nominator

I have way more than the minimum staking limit on Polkadot. But I suddenly stopped reviewing rewards a few months ago. So I added some mode $Dots to my account and went through this process:
1- Bond more Dots
2- Rebag using PolkadotJS wallet linked to my ledger Nano S
3- Move up my account
which was only working for a few days and I stopped earning rewards again. This time I bonded less amount of Dots to move my account on top of the lower bag. Then I moved up but it did not help to receive rewards either. Any idea what should I do?

Note: I have changed my validators several times. And I was careful and aware of how to select them. I have read this [article](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000170805-why-am-i-not-getting-staking-rewards-) also and took it into consideration but didn’t help

I have also checked the validators. 15/16 of them were active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems the minimum staking amount has been increased and thanks to [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9611/3846) answer now I know what was the reason.