# Why is it required to have 405.1869 DOT in solo staking?

Tags: polkadot, staking, wallet

I am currently using Ledger Nano S to stake Dot but I am unable to receive rewards. I checked Polkadot's official website which says the minimum amount to receive rewards is 120Dot (My current bonded Dots are already higher than that) but I also checked PolkaGate Wallet's Solo Staking tab which says the minimum amount to stake is 405.1869 DOT. Which one is correct? Is it the reason I am unable to receive the rewards?

[image]

Comment: Can you point me to the link that mentions 120 DOT please?

Comment: It was here I checked a few months ago https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking but it is still available on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Polkadot/comments/s8hmkc/minimum_dot_for_staking_rewards/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair point, where I can guide you to the Polkadot Wiki specifically the Staking section:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking

[image]

You will see it says 405.187 as of time of writing this.

I'd much rather guide you to the onchain canonical source where the min active stake is stored (staking > `minimumActiveStake`):

[image]

You can also find this number in the Polkadot Staking Dashboard:

- https://staking.polkadot.network/#/nominate

Also, for some this number is bar to entry and the suggestion there is to use a nomination pool.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it.